# Tar exclude hidden files but use relative paths?

Tags: tar, xz

Using the following command:

```
tar --exclude="./.*" -czvf /Volumes/Foo/2016-04-14_2051_full.tar.xz ./
```

Which follows [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38108/why-does-tar-exclude-create-an-empty-archive) advice, still gets also hidden files archived:

```
a .
a ./.Trashes
a ./.fseventsd
a ./data
```

What can I do to only get the `./data` folder archived?

**Update**: I use a Mac and zsh shell.

Comment: `tar -czvf /some/output/file.xz ./data`?

Comment: Sorry, I was not clear .. I have a lot of folders underneath so `./data2` ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I now used the workaround:

```
XZ_OPT=-9e tar --exclude='./old' --exclude='.*' -cJvf /Volumes/Foo/$(date +%Y%m%dT%H%M)_full.tar.xz * -g incremetal
```

Hope it helps someone else as well